# Reduce json api document to camel case

Tags: javascript

I would like to reduce a json api standard document to a camel version. I was able to make a `camelCase` objects and single primitive types keys.

I would like the desired output to be every key to be `camelCase`. So in the example above `first-name` would turn into `firstName`, `snake-case` would turn into `snakeCase`. The problem I'm facing is how to approach an array of objects using the same recursive call I'm using right now.

```js
import _ from "lodash";

const data = {
  id: 1,
  type: "user",
  links: { self: "/movies/1" },
  meta: { "is-saved": false },
  "first-name": "Foo",
  "last-name": "Bar",
  locations: ["SF"],
  actors: [
    { id: 1, type: "actor", name: "John", age: 80 },
    { id: 2, type: "actor", name: "Jenn", age: 40 }
  ],
  awards: [
    {
      id: 4,
      type: "Oscar",
      links: ["asd"],
      meta: ["bar"],
      category: "Best director",
      'snake_case': 'key should be snakeCase'
    }
  ],
  name: { id: 1, type: "name", title: "Stargate" }
};

const needsCamelCase = str => {
  return str.indexOf("-") > -1 || str.indexOf("_") > -1;
};

const strToCamelCase = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/^([A-Z])|[\s-_](\w)/g, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
    if (p2) return p2.toUpperCase();
    return p1.toLowerCase();
  });
};

const toCamelCase = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (_.isPlainObject(obj[key])) {
      return toCamelCase(obj[key]);
    }

    if (_.isArray(obj[key])) {
      // console.log(obj[key]);
      obj[key].forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
      });
      //obj[key].foreach(element_ =>  toCamelCase);
    }

    if (needsCamelCase(key)) {
      obj[strToCamelCase(key)] = obj[key];
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });

  return obj;
};

// toCamelCase(data);
console.log(toCamelCase(data));
```

Here is a codesand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-l842u

Comment: Any reason you have lodash imported but you don't use the `_.camelCase` function ?

Comment: @FlorianThuin Had no idea lodash had a camelCase function. Thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic is quite simple: if it's an object, just call to `toCamelCase`, if it's an array, iterate over it to create a new array. If it's an array of object, transform it with `toCamelCase`, if it's an array of something else keep it as is.

The solution would probably look like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const data = {
  id: 1,
  type: "user",
  links: { self: "/movies/1" },
  meta: { "is-saved": false },
  "first-name": "Foo",
  "last-name": "Bar",
  locations: ["SF"],
  actors: [
    { id: 1, type: "actor", name: "John", age: 80 },
    { id: 2, type: "actor", name: "Jenn", age: 40 }
  ],
  awards: [
    {
      id: 4,
      type: "Oscar",
      links: ["asd"],
      meta: ["bar"],
      category: "Best director",
      'snake_case': 'key should be snakeCase'
    }
  ],
  name: { id: 1, type: "name", title: "Stargate" }
};

const needsCamelCase = str => {
  return str.indexOf("-") > -1 || str.indexOf("_") > -1;
};

const strToCamelCase = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/^([A-Z])|[\s-_](\w)/g, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
    if (p2) return p2.toUpperCase();
    return p1.toLowerCase();
  });
};

const toCamelCase = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const camelCasedKey = needsCamelCase(key) ? strToCamelCase(key) : key;
    const value = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
    obj[camelCasedKey] = value;

    if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
      obj[camelCasedKey] = toCamelCase(value);
    }

    if (_.isArray(value)) {
      obj[camelCasedKey] = value.map(item => {
        if (_.isPlainObject(item)) {
          return toCamelCase(item);
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return obj;
};

// toCamelCase(data);
console.log(toCamelCase(data));
```